# HTML5 Websockets - will this allow me to communicate with host machine?

Tags: html, com, serial-port, websocket

I want my web application to communicate with a serial device on a host machine (e.g. a card reader). I don't want to use the ActiveX/COM route. Is there something in HTML5 websockets that could help me?

Comment: You could do websockets with java and Netty also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code example for a serial-to-WebSocket gateway is here:

https://github.com/oberstet/Autobahn/tree/master/demo/serial2ws

This is based on Autobahn WebSockets .. and is possible because Autobahn is based on Twisted, and Twisted has support for serial, XMPP, ... many things.

Disclaimer: I'm author of Autobahn.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Web Sockets could help.

Take a look at this, it is using web sockets for a micro-controller: http://blaisejarrett.com/websockets/

Comment: Uses Autobahn WebSockets .. code here is probably easier to get going for beginners:

https://github.com/oberstet/Autobahn/tree/master/demo/serial2ws